# Plumbing vent odor on rooftop deck

Tags: plumbing, vent, drain-waste-vent, smell

Just bought a place that came with an accessible rooftop and there's a plumbing vent that creates a pretty noticeable odor when near it. Our inspector provided a recommendation to put the vent cap on that you see in the picture. Based on my searches, a vent line like this on an occupied roof should extend to no less than 7' above the floor which I think will help with the smell as the vent sits ~2' lower than all of the surrounding walls.

My question is, is it as easy as putting a male-to-male coupling and an extra run of PVC pipe to get the opening higher up or is there something wrong with doing it that way?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just extending the pipe from where it is would make a weak point at the joint.

Use 90Deg. elbows and run the pipe toward the wall and anchor it there after turning vertical again.  Then having the pipe rise another 5 or 6 feet should place any smelly gas above peoples heads, without making the pipe susceptible to breaking in a brisk wind.

Just remember to put a slight slope in the horizontal section toward the original vent, so any water that gets in runs down the vent and doesn't sit in the horizontal section.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense so I'll go that route.

Answer (score -1):

Before you do that I would get an auto vent and see if that works for you. It will let air in but no odor out and you won’t have run any pipe.

Comment: If you're referring to an air admittance valve, those have a nasty tendency to fail and need replacement on a regular basis. They're usually only used indoors, in an island where there is no way to run a standard vent. I doubt there are many that are actually designed for outdoor use. Additionally, it's hard to imagine that an AAV would be less expensive than a few feet of pipe, especially when one considers replacement costs of AAVs vs the one-time cost of pipe.